Killing a process using TerminateProcess
I am writing a program on MASM64, the goal of the program is to launch the calc.exe process (a regular Windows calculator) and after 10 seconds complete this process. I expect the program to close completely after the process completes, but the window continues to hang and function. Please correct the code or suggest any functions for this
include \masm64\include64\masm64rt.inc
.data
buff dd 0 ;
programname db "c:\windows\system32\calc.exe",0
;programname db "1-1.exe",0
titl db 'Level 0',0
frmt db 'My ProcID = %i (decimal)',0
startInfo dd ?
processInfo PROCESS_INFORMATION <> ; 

.code
entry_point proc

    invoke CreateProcess,ADDR programname,0,0,0,FALSE,\
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0,0,ADDR startInfo,ADDR processInfo

    cmp eax, 0
    jz process_failed
    
    invoke MessageBox, 0, addr buff, "The process was created successfully", MB_ICONINFORMATION+180000h

    invoke TerminateProcess, processInfo.hProcess, 1
        
    cmp eax, 0
    jz process_failed

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
    
    process_failed:
    invoke MessageBox, 0, addr buff, "Error", MB_ICONINFORMATION+180000h
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
    
invoke ExitProcess,0
entry_point endp
end


On modern Windows, calc.exe simply launches the calc app then exits. You need to test using a different program such as cmd.exe.
